# how many calories per unit of sweetness between table sugar and aspartame?

Tags: physical-chemistry

How many calories per unit of sweetness between table sugar and aspartame?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry Stack Exchange. This is a question that could easily be answered by using your favor internet search for "sucrose calories" and "aspartame calories". Can you give us a little bit more information on how this information is hard for you to find or interpret?

Comment: This is the wrong question to ask. The right question is "how many calories per unit of sweetness". Even if the calories per gram are the same, the calories to give a specific amount of sweetness (the primary use of the molecules) is all that matters in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Aspartame 4 calories per gram [source](https://foodinsight.org/everything-you-need-to-know-about-aspartame/)

Sucrose 3.9 calories per gram [source](https://www.nutrientsreview.com/carbs/disaccharides-sucrose.html)

But you need far less aspartame than sucrose to get the same level of perceived sweetness

Comment: I believe in giving good answers to questions even if the question is not quite there yet. In this case, it is clear what the question is, even if it is not clearly formulated. It would be nice to address the lack of "denominator" in the question, i.e. calories per what.